# mysql conditional query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: files and user.

```
files
----------------------------
|Fileid  | name  | type    |
----------------------------
| 01     | file1 | private |
| 02     | file2 | private |
| 03     | file3 | Public  |
----------------------------
```

and

```
user
---------------------
| Fileid  | UserId  |
---------------------
| 01      | user1   | 
| 02      | user1   |
---------------------
```

How would I select all the record(private and public) for who ever id is in the 'user' table and only 'public' files for any other user where the 'userid' is not in the 'user' table? please help

Comment: this question is strangely formatted and confusingly described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand the problem, you are looking for a `LEFT JOIN` favoring `files` returning all fields for non-null `UserId`, or `Public` only when `UserId IS NULL`.

```
SELECT 
  files.*
FROM files LEFT JOIN user ON files.Fileid = user.Fileid
WHERE 
  user.UserId IS NOT NULL
  OR (user.UserId IS NULL AND files.type = 'Public')
```

Comment: i think this is the solution which i was looking for,let me try and see.Thanks @Michael

Comment: That query would do the trick, except for that you have a typo in your parenthesis; user.User.Id should be user.UserId

Comment: @Marcus Just fixed as you were commenting.

Comment: Hi @Michael ,its not really working ... can it be because of user.UserId IS NOT NULL" ?

Comment: got it working after changing the field to be null able ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need 2 loops for the first part. one loop will get the user IDs from the table. and the second loop should be placed inside the first one. the second will use the ID in the loop to get all the files.

Second part can be done by having a loop with a sql query like `SELECT * FROM files WHERE userID != $userID[$i]` and $userID should be an array with all of your users ID.

NOTE : I assumed that you forgot to include a foreign key in the files table to connect both tables together.

Comment: Ahoura Ghotbi,thanks for the reply...is there a way i can do it in the query itself?

Comment: Yea if I am not mistaking you can use the union function in SQL and get all the IDs and then compare them with your other table to see if they are there.